# Error selector is not known element in angular

Tags: angular, asp.net-mvc-5

I am building an Angular 4 app integrated with MVC 5. I am creating a Movie component that has a  template that I am injecting into app.component.html. I have made the necessary references of the movie component in the app.module but I get the error

```
'app-movie' is not a known element:
1. If 'app-movie' is an Angular component, then verify that it is part of this module.
If 'app-movie' is a Web Component then add 'CUSTOM_ELEMENTS_SCHEMA' to the '@NgModule.schemas' of this component to suppress this message. ("
<div>
    <h1>{{pageTitle}}</h1>
    [ERROR ->]<app-movie></app-movie>
</div>

")
```

The code is as below

**app.module**

```
import { NgModule } from "@angular/core";
import { AppComponent } from "./app.component";
import { BrowserModule} from "@angular/platform-browser";
import { FormsModule } from '@angular/forms';
import { HttpModule } from '@angular/http';
import { MovieModule } from '../movie/movie.module';
import { MovieComponent } from '../movie/movie.component';


@NgModule({
    imports: [
              BrowserModule,
              FormsModule,
              HttpModule,
              MovieModule
    ],
    declarations: [AppComponent, MovieComponent],
    bootstrap: [AppComponent]
})

export class AppModule {

}
```

**app.component.ts**

```
import { Component } from "@angular/core";

@Component({
    selector: "mrdb-app",
    templateUrl: "./Scripts/app/app.component.html"

})


export class AppComponent {

    pageTitle: string = "Movies Review Database";

}
```

**app.component.html**

```
<div>
    <h1>{{pageTitle}}</h1>
    <app-movie></app-movie>  //This selector belongs to movie component
</div>
```

**movie.component.ts**

```
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';

@Component({
    selector: 'app-movie',
    templateUrl: './Scripts/movie/movie-list.component.html'

})
export class MovieComponent implements OnInit {

    pageTitle: string = "Movie List";

    constructor() { }

    ngOnInit() {
    }

}

Movie-list.component.html
//Assume I have written a logic to display list of movies

Movie-Add.component.html
//Assume I have written a html for data entry screen
```

**Movie Module**

```
import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';
import { CommonModule } from '@angular/common';
import { MovieComponent } from './movie.component';

@NgModule({
    imports: [
        CommonModule
    ],
    declarations: [MovieComponent],
    exports: [MovieComponent]
})
export class MovieModule { }
```

Comment: Are you using asp.net core angular2 template with server rendering?

Comment: `MovieComponent` should belong to only one `@NgModule` but i see you declared it in `MovieModule` and `AppModule`

Comment: One thing I notice is that you declared `MovieComponent` in both `AppModule` and `MoiveModule`. You should only declare it once

Comment: why are you injecting templates inside app.component.html? It is better to create sub components of app component. i:e add movie component, list movie component, single movie component etc then use '@Input' & '@Output' decorators to pass data from parent to child and vise-versa. Communication between components is much easier and better.

Answer (score 0):

Remove **`MovieComponent`** From the **`AppModule`** , it will be acting as a shared Component since you are already importing the module **`MovieModule`**

```
@NgModule({
    imports: [
              BrowserModule,
              FormsModule,
              HttpModule,
              MovieModule
    ],
    declarations: [AppComponent],
    bootstrap: [AppComponent]
})

export class AppModule {

}
```

Answer (score 0):

Since you have `imported` `MovieModule` into app.module and `MovieComponent` is already exported from it so no need to explicitly `declare` `MovieComponent` in app.module

Try below code

```
import { NgModule } from "@angular/core";
import { AppComponent } from "./app.component";
import { BrowserModule} from "@angular/platform-browser";
import { FormsModule } from '@angular/forms';
import { HttpModule } from '@angular/http';
import { MovieModule } from '../movie/movie.module';


@NgModule({
    imports: [
              BrowserModule,
              FormsModule,
              HttpModule,
              MovieModule
    ],
    declarations: [AppComponent],
    bootstrap: [AppComponent]
})

export class AppModule {

}
```

Comment: what is the difference from the answer i posted

Comment: May be I posted before your post. So same question from my side.

Comment: check the time dude! i posted before 7 minutes you post

Comment: Sahi hai, You won the match then ;)